# How to selectively disable tracker indexing a certain (set of) directories

Tags: tracker

I often build large projects. An example is a site that is built with Jekyll. The build takes about 20 seconds, and changes thousands of HTML files. The same happens when I build the documentation of some projects.

Tracker store picks this up, and then starts indexing them, causing huge CPU spikes.

1. I don't need tracker to index these build-artifacts.
2. The build artifacts go into one, or at most a very few, known directories, but these might have subdirectories.
3. I do want tracker to keep indexing most of my system, I like the features it offers on Ubuntu.

Is it possible to selectively disable tracker indexing or monitoring a certain directory and its subdirectories? On e.g. Android a `.nomedia` file avoids Android from indexing it: does something like this exist for Tracker, or is there another kind of config for this?

Comment: @pomsky I'm not sure that tracker-preferences are available in 17.10 - do you know if the name of the application has changed to something else?

Comment: Have you tried to go to **Preferences**-> **Search** -> clicking the cogwheel ? You can disable all search locations here, and add customized one with **Other**-> **+**

Comment: Don't forget the **Bookmark** tab. After you have modified the settings you can use `tracker daemon -t`to stop it and `tracker dameon -s` to start it. `tracker status` should show you how many files/directories it found, and if the indexing has finished

Comment: @CharlesGreen Apparently Tracker is not installed by default in Ubuntu 17.10 as per [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes). But this question is specifically about Tracker, it does not mention 17.10.

Comment: @pomsky K - I've got tracker installed as a dependency of 'Vanilla-Gnome-Desktop' - I mentioned 17.10 as the OP did not mention OS version...

Comment: @CharlesGreen The command [`tracker-preferences` is from the `tracker-gui` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/tracker-gui), but you're right, it seems the package is [not available for Artful!](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tracker-gui) So I think this question may be marked as a duplicate of the other if it's about Trusty or Xenial, but should not be closed as a duplicate if it's about Artful. Need clarification from OP.